# Dialog box for controller action in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii, model, controller

What is the meaning of this function in yii "asDialog".I tried to google but couldn't find it anywhere. Also I saw this in the code for a dialog box for particular action in the controller.Can anyone explain the meaning of this function?

```
public function actionCreate()
{   
    $model=new Vegetable;
    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        $this->renderPartial('create', array('model'=>$model, 'asDialog'=>!empty($_GET['asDialog']),), false, true);
        Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($_GET['returnUrl']);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    else 
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Vegetable']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Vegetable'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::$model->image;
            if($model->save())
            {
                echo "hi";
                //$model->image->saveAs(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/vegetables/').$model->image);
                $model->image->saveAs(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/carausel/'.$model->image);
                //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
            $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you see this function? in some documentation? or in someone`s code?

Comment: I saw it in a code .I will paste it..

Comment: please have a look at renderPartial in yii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for `CController::renderPartial()`, is an array of data to be extracted into PHP variables and made available to the view script.

The keys in that array, `model` and `asDialog`, are only useful/meaningful to the corresponding view page, and does not configure the renderPartial method.

This means that in the view page *create.php*, the page can access the PHP variables `$model` and `$asDialog`.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail